# C++: strcpy Function copies null?

Tags: c++, string, null

While using string manipulation functions specificaly `strcpy` I did this small program.

```
char s1[8]="Hellopo";
char s2[4]="sup";
strcpy(s1,s2);
cout<<s1<<endl;
```

When I printed out s1 It actually just printed out "sup". I expected it to print "suplopo".

Then I did this:

`cout<<s1+4 << endl;`

It printed out "opo";

And The output of this: `cout<<s1+3<<endl;`  was nothing

So after thinking a bit about it.

I came to this conclusion. Since C++ stops outputing the string once it reaches the null terminator. Therefore the null must have been copied in the `strcpy` function. Resulting in this string:

s - u - p - \0 - o - p - o -\0;

Please tell me if this is correct or not. And if im not please correct me.

And if you have any more info to provide please do.

Comment: Looks right to me. Your tests seem to bear that out. Though a debugger will show you what's in each byte of the char arrays.

Comment: The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy. http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, and would have easily been confirmed by any decent [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

> The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by `dest`.

Answer (score 5):

Your reasoning regarding the copying of the terminating character is correct. The C++ standard (which is the definitive specification for the language) defers to C on this matter (for example, C++14 defers to C99, and C++17 defers to C11).

The C11 standard has this to say about `strcpy`:

> **7.24.2.3 The `strcpy` function**
>
> *Synopsis:*
>
> > `#include <string.h>`
> > `char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);`
>
> *Description:*
>
> > The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by `s1`. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> *Returns:*
>
> > The `strcpy` function returns the value of `s1`.

If you just wanted to replace the first three characters of your string, you can use `memcpy()` to copy a specific number of bytes:

```
memcpy(s1, s2, strlen(s2));
```

Keep in mind that this will just copy those bytes and nothing more. If `s1` isn't already a string of at least the length of `s2`, it's unlikely to end well :-)

---

And just keep one thing in mind re your comment "... resulting in this string: <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>\0</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>\0</kbd>".

That is *not* a string. A string in C (and a legacy string in C++) is defined as a series of characters up to and including the *first* `\0` terminator.

You may well have a series of characters up to the original (now second) `\0` but the *string* is actually shorter than that. This may *seem* a little pedantic but it's important to understand the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. For the effect you initially expected, you would use `strncopy`. `strncopy` copies the null terminator as long as you specify the correct length of the string that is being copied.

Comment: `strncpy` will also copy the null terminator, if there's space. For the expected effect, you'd want something like `memcpy(s1, s2, strlen(s2))`.

Comment: `strncpy(s1,s2,strlen(s2))` should also not copy the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page for `strcpy`:

> The `strcpy()` function  copies the string pointed to by `src`,
>   including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer  pointed  to
>   by `dest`. The  strings  may  not overlap, and the destination string
>   `dest` must be large enough to receive the copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html

> The strcpy() function shall copy the string pointed to by s2
>   **(including the terminating null byte)** into the array pointed to by s1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.  strcpy will include the null terminator.  It's important as if you copy the string to a new memory block you want it null terminated by default.  I believe strncpy might be what you're after in this case.

Also I know it was only testing code but I'd be careful in this day and age of using +X offsets in strings... ascii normally bites people in the rear end in the utf8/unicode world we now live in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in your reasoning and if you would have explicitly typecast-ed the 4th character 's1[3]' as integer like this:

cout<<(int)s1[3];

You would have gotten "0" as the output which is the ASCII value of NULL character.